# Why Are The UITableView's Cells Being Inserted Above The Table Header?

Tags: xcode8, ios10

The question and the screen shots pretty much say it all. The cells are being created from a nib that has been registered with the tables.

[image: xcode interface builder]

[image: iPhone simulator]

Update: I decided to dig in with lldb:

```
(lldb) po servicesTable.tableHeaderView  
nil

(lldb) po characteristicsTable.tableHeaderView  
nil
```

The header views are nil! Does this mean that I am being fooled by what I see on my storyboard? That I have not actually created table headers?

Let's keep digging:

```
`(lldb) po characteristicsTable!.subviews
▿ 4 elements
  - 0 : <UITableViewWrapperView: 0x7f89f4840a00; frame = (0 0; 343 270.5); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x610000051070>; layer = <CALayer: 0x61000003df00>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {343, 270.5}>
  - 1 : <UIImageView: 0x7f89f2d1c6a0; frame = (3 265; 337 2.5); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000224840>>
  - 2 : <UIView: 0x7f89f50162a0; frame = (0 100; 343 44); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x618000039e80>>
  - 3 : <UIImageView: 0x7f89f2c1c370; frame = (337.5 179.5; 2.5 88); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x6080004241e0>>`
```

`(lldb) po characteristicsTable!.subviews[2].subviews
▿ 2 elements
  - 0 : <UILabel: 0x7f89f5016570; frame = (8 8; 327 28); text = 'Characteristics'; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x61800008cbc0>>
  - 1 : <UIButton: 0x7f89f2d06f40; frame = (313 11; 22 22); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000223300>>`

Alright, the characteristics table sub view at index 2 is the one that we see labeled as "Header" in the storyboard's document outline (i.e. a view containing a label with the text "Characteristics" and a button).

Lets try this:

`(lldb) expression characteristicsTable.tableHeaderView = characteristicsTable.subviews[2]`

Voila! The characteristics table's header is positioned properly.

[image]

From all of this I am concluding that I do not know how to drag a view onto a table and have it become the table's header. Can anyone advise? (I will continue to experiment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use the Interface Builder to add a table header to a UITableView, drag a view onto the table view's entry in the document outline. **DO NOT** drag the view onto the table view's rendering in the storyboard. Jeez! These type of subtleties are darned exasperating.

`(lldb) po servicesTable.tableHeaderView
▿ Optional<UIView>`